# PyQt Принятая по serialport строка разбивается на три

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, serialport

Пишу простое приложение для работы с SerialPort.
В Qt Desinger сделал окошко для выбора порта и коннекта, принятые данные пишутся в терминал VScode.
Использую для проверки "Virtual Serial Ports Emulator".
При коннекте между собой двух терминалов "Terminal v1.9b" данные отправляются корректно, если использую "Terminal v1.9b" в связке со своей программой то принятые данные с терминала бьются на три строки каждый раз разной длинны.
При использовании терминала "Termite" данные/строка принимаются моей программой корректно.
Также пробовал принимать данные с микроконтроллера через uart с него поступает строчка (массив) такого вида: "uf000F000t" без возврата каретки и начала новой строки, в Тerminal v1.9b данные как и задумывалось принимаются одной длинной строкой (uf000F000tuf000F000tuf000F000tuf000F000t и т.д.), а в моей программе каждый символ с новой строки.
Собственно вопрос почему строка бьется на три, а при отправке с микроконтроллера каждый символ с новой строки?

Код:

```css
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from threading import *
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi("MainWindow.ui")
ui.closePortBut.setEnabled(False)


serial = QSerialPort()
serial.setBaudRate(9600)

# обновить список портов
def updateList():
    portList = []
    ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
    for port in ports: portList.append(port.portName()) 
    ui.comBox.clear()
    ui.comBox.addItems(portList)

# open serial port
def onOpen():
    serial.setPortName(ui.comBox.currentText())
    serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    if serial.OpenMode:
        print("openPort")
        ui.openPortBut.setEnabled(False)
        ui.closePortBut.setEnabled(True)

# закрыть порт
def onClose():
    serial.close()
    print("closePort")
    ui.openPortBut.setEnabled(True)
    ui.closePortBut.setEnabled(False)

# прочитать порт
def onRead():
    rx = serial.readLine()
    rxStrnig = str(rx, "utf-8")
    print(rxStrnig)


serial.readyRead.connect(onRead)
ui.openPortBut.clicked.connect(onOpen)
ui.closePortBut.clicked.connect(onClose)
updateList()


ui.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - в многозадачной ОС (не важно какой), данные буферизуются - то что программа пишет в порт, сначала поступает в буфер ввода - вывода, а потом драйвер последовательного порта потихоньку отсылает это на устройство.

Верно и обратное - то что присылает устройство, драйвер складывает в буфер, после чего буфер сбрасывается в приложение.

Наличие буфера обусловлено, в частности, наличием многозадачности - приложение, передающее данные, в данный момент может быть вытеснено планировщиком CPU, а данные куда-то девать надо.

Аналогично работают сетевые протоколы, например, TCP.

Чтобы ваше приложение работало корректно, вам нужен свой протокол обмена данными, работающий через UART.

В частности, вам нужно:

1. Правильно синхронизировать устройство и компьютер, потому что может случиться так, что устройство работало-работало, и тут его подключили к ПК - и вы начали получать сообщения с середины.
2. Обеспечить обозначение начала и конца сообщения.

Обе данные задачи решаются при помощи, например, использования маркера конца сообщения - например, последовательности байт 0x0D0A (`"\r\n"`). Понятно, что внутри сообщения эти байты вам придется либо экранировать (например `"\\r\\n"`, либо никогда не использовать.

Comment: Добавил в функцию `onRead()` проверку целостности строки через `canReadLine()` и в конец строки  добавляю \n (0A) - работает, но как быть если я хочу использовать свои символы начала и конца строки?

Comment: @Mastech - очевидно, вам в таком случае придется писать свою canReadLine(), которая будет работать с вашими концами строк, но выглядеть это будет странненько - есть стандартные символы, с ними работают все - вам же хочется разнообразия.